# TypeError: must be str, not Statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, chatbot, chatterbot

I am working on a chatbot and the code is -

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
import nltk
import numpy as np
import random
import string # to process standard python strings

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

import os  
language = 'en'

remove_punct_dict = dict((ord(punct), None) for punct in string.punctuation)

GREETING_INPUTS = ("hello", "hi", "greetings", "sup", "what's up","hey","hii")
GREETING_RESPONSES = ["hi", "hey", "*nods*", "hi there", "hello", "I am glad! You are talking to me"]

def greeting(sentence): 
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word.lower() in GREETING_INPUTS:
            greetinput = random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES)
            return greetinput


def response(user_response):
    robo_response=''
    user_response = str(user_response)
    robo_response = robo_response+return_response
    return robo_response

flag=True

my_bot = ChatBot(name='PyBot', read_only=True,logic_adapters=['chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation','chatterbot.logic.BestMatch'])
small_talk = ['hi there!',
              'hi!',
              'how do you do?',
              'how are you?',
              'i\'m cool.',
              'fine, you?',
              'always cool.',
              'i\'m ok',
              'glad to hear that.',
              'i\'m fine',
              'glad to hear that.',
              'i feel awesome',
              'excellent, glad to hear that.',
              'not so good',
              'sorry to hear that.',
              'what\'s your name?',
              'i\'m pybot. ask me a math question, please.']

math_talk_1 = ['pythagorean theorem',
           'a squared plus b squared equals c squared.']

math_talk_2 = ['law of cosines',
           'c**2 = a**2 + b**2 - 2 * a * b * cos(gamma)']


list_trainer = ListTrainer(my_bot)

for item in (small_talk, math_talk_1, math_talk_2):
    list_trainer.train(item)

corpus_trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(my_bot)
corpus_trainer.train('chatterbot.corpus.english')


openremark = "ROBO: My name is Robo. I will answer your queries about Chatbots. If you want to exit, type Bye!"

print("ROBO: My name is Robo. I will answer your queries about Chatbots. If you want to exit, type Bye!")

while(flag==True):
    user_response = input()
    user_response=user_response.lower()
    if(user_response!='bye'):
        if(user_response=='thanks' or user_response=='thank you' ):
            flag=False
            print("ROBO: You are welcome..")
        else:
            if(greeting(user_response)!=None):
                print("ROBO: "+greeting(user_response))
            else:
                print("ROBO: ",end="")
                print("func call user_response")
                print(user_response)
                print("end")
                user_response = str(user_response)
                print(response(user_response))
    else:
        flag=False

        offremark2 = "Bye! take care"
        print("ROBO: Bye! take care..")
```

On run command it is not working fine -

```
ROBO: My name is Robo. I will answer your queries about Chatbots. If you want to exit, type Bye!
hi
ROBO: hi there
gaurav
ROBO: func call user_response
gaurav
end
user_response
gaurav
type
<class 'str'>
end
dummy check
you are busy
dummy end
user_response
gaurav
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chatbot-new-1.py", line 118, in <module>
    print(response(user_response))
  File "chatbot-new-1.py", line 46, in response
    robo_response = robo_response+return_response
TypeError: must be str, not Statement
```

It is working fine for greeting and *BYE* message but when it has to work with CHATTERBOT and CHATTERBOT_CORPUS it is giving an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chatbot-new-1.py", line 118, in <module>
    print(response(user_response))
  File "chatbot-new-1.py", line 46, in response
    robo_response = robo_response+return_response
TypeError: must be str, not Statement
```

TypeError: must be str, not Statement

I even tried with making user_response string first and also with for loop so that it work for each singular element but it turn up the same message. I am not able to resolve the error and didnt get any answer for the same or similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `return_response` ? It doesn't look like it's defined.

Maybe replace this :

```
robo_response = robo_response+return_response
```

by this :

```
robo_response = robo_response+user_response
```

Comment: If you look at the chatbot program user_ response is the response enter by user on CMD and return_response is the response that CHATBOT should return on CMD. If I change the value of robo_response as you suggested it will loose its sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for making a best bot first install **English** folder from chatterbot corpse from **GitHub**

```
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot import ChatBot
bot = ChatBot('Text')
conv = open('english/ai.yml','r').readlines()

bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)
bot.train(conv)

while True:
    request = input('you:')
    response = bot.get_response(request)
    print('Bot: ', response())
```